# Ruby on Rails Bundle install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gemfile

I am relatively new to RoR, when installing the Gemfile's I get the following error message:

```
!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end. Bundler cannot continue.

#  from /Users/moof/Documents/workspace/sample/top_app/Gemfile:48
#  -------------------------------------------
#  
>  
#  -------------------------------------------
```

My Gemfille looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do

gem 'byebug'            
  gem 'sqlite3'                         
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0.0.beta4'
  gem 'spring'              

group :development do 
  gem 'pg'                      
  gem 'rails_12factor' 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 blocks and one end:

```
group :development, :test do

gem 'byebug'            
  gem 'sqlite3'                         
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0.0.beta4'
  gem 'spring'              

group :development do 
  gem 'pg'                      
  gem 'rails_12factor' 

end
```

try this instead:

```
group :development, :test do

gem 'byebug'            
  gem 'sqlite3'                         
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0.0.beta4'
  gem 'spring'
end              

group :development do 
  gem 'pg'                      
  gem 'rails_12factor' 

end
```